# It keeps me looping even though I don't have any loops

Tags: java, arrays, oop, subclass, superclass

> I don't know what is wrong but it keeps me looping even though I pressed or entered 1 and I want it to call the subclass agent it doesn't but when I press 2 it calls the subclass what is wrong here I've been at it for 5-7hrs I think and my eyes be balling

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Person 
{
protected String agentId = "20860132";
protected String password = "20020729" ;
protected String address;

public Person(String agentId,String password, String address) 
{
    this.agentId = agentId;
    this.password = password;
    this.address = address;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("[1]AGENT");
    System.out.println("[2]CUSTOMER");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    

    //here is where the code loops it just keeps repeating this lines 
   "System.out.println("[1]AGENT"); System.out.println("[2]CUSTOMER");"

    if(choice == 1) 
    {
       Agent agent = new Agent("Niel", "diko alam", "umay");
    }   
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("POTANGINA");
    }   
}
}
```

> the block of code up here is suppose to call this class

```
class Agent extends Person 
{

public Agent(String agentId, String password, String address) 
{
super(agentId, password, address);
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("[LOGIN]");
System.out.print("ENTER AGENT ID:");
int id = input2.nextInt();
System.out.print("ENTER PASSWORD:");
int pass = input2.nextInt();
if(id == 20860132 && pass == 20020729)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("[1]ADD CAR");
    System.out.println("[2]SCHEDULE");
    System.out.println("[3]RECORDS");
    int choice2 = input.nextInt();

if(choice2 == 1)
 {   
    boolean stopFlag = false;
    do 
    {
        List<String>cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("[CARS]");
        cars.add("Tayota");
        cars.add("Hillux");
        cars.add("Bugatti");
        System.out.println(cars);
        System.out.println("Enter Car:");
        String car = input.nextLine();
        cars.add(car);
        System.out.println("Would you like to add more?");
        System.out.println("[1]YES");
        System.out.println("[2]NO");
        String choice3 = input.nextLine();
        addCar(cars);
        if(!choice3.equals(1))
        stopFlag = true;
    }while(!stopFlag);
 }
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("INCORRECT PLEASE TRY AGAIN.");
}
}

public void addCar(List<String> cars) 
{
    try 
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cars.txt", true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(cars);
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void schedule(String schedule) 
{
    try 
    {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("schedule.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    pw.println(schedule);
    pw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void records(String record) 
    {
     try
        {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("records.txt", true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(record);
        pw.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}




class Customer extends Person 
{
private String customerId;

public Customer(String agentId, String password, String address, String customerId) 
{
super(agentId, password, address);
this.customerId = customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(String customerId) 
{
this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getCustomerId() 
{
return customerId;
}

public void rentCar(String car) 
{

    try 
    {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cars.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    pw.println(car);
    pw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void viewSchedule(String schedule) 
{
    try 
    {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("schedule.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    pw.println(schedule);
    pw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void extend(String record) 
{
    try 
    {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("records.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    pw.println(record);
    pw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

> Here is the main method

```
public class Finals 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Person person = new Person("20860132", "h208f32", "San luis");
       Agent agent = new Agent("20860132", "h208f32", "San luis");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can merge the code together? It is very hard to read with the splitted code-blocks.

Comment: In the constructor of `Person`, your create an instance of `Agent`, which is a subclass of `Person`. Subclasses call their superclass's constructor. That's the infinite loop here.

Answer (score 5):

First line in the constructor of Agent calls super, which is the constructor of Person that will ask for input 1 and 2 again. That is your 'loop'. When you select 1, it will start creating another Agent object which will do the same thing again. If you keep selecting '1' you will never get past the super call in Agent.

Put the printing/input logic somewhere else, like in your main method. Constructors should be simple. For example, the logic in your Person constructor, move that to a static method in your Finals class (`public static void createPerson`) with the same arguments as what the constructor now has, and then call that from your main method instead of `new Person`. There is still much to improve beyond that, but that will probably fix your 'loop'.